How to exclude values that have a percentage sign (%) in Oracle SQL
I have a query that brings in a column like the example below



Column A




5.3


8.452


7.3%


2.1


2.28


6.4


9.1645


8.81



I want to ideally drop the % sign otherwise exclude the value that has a percentage sign (%) on the end. However, I'm not sure how to do this in Oracle SQL since the % sign is used as the wildcard in strings.
Does anyone know of a way I can exclude these values?
I normally would use the INSTR to cut off after the second decimal but the numbers are not uniform in length and I can't use a round function to get them the same length since the source data has the values as strings.

You can add an escape clause to the like operator to specify the escape character you're using:
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  col_a NOT LIKE '%\%' ESCAPE '\'


Drop the percentage sign?
update mytable set col = replace(col, '%');

If you want to do this in the query only, not in the table, then:
select replace(col, '%') from mytable;

It is strange that you get that mix, anyway. Are you dealing with a column that is supposed to hold numeric values, but is defined as a string? Then I'd replace that string column with a numeric one.


I want to ideally drop the % sign

You can use replace() to, well, replace the % sign with something else, or in this case with nothing:
select replace(column_a, '%') as column_a
from your_table;

which gives you the output



COLUMN_A




5.3


8.452


7.3


2.1


2.28


6.4


9.1645


8.81



fiddle
Holding numeric and sort-of numeric data together as strings seems like a data model problem. You could put other non-numeric characters in there, or mix up the decimal separator if someone from another territory insert a number and relies on implicit conversion. The scale is also not clear - is 7.3% really 7.3, or 0.073? etc.

One option is to use instr function; as far as I understood, you do not want to get values with the percentage sign in result. If that's so, then - for sample data
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '5.3'  from dual union all
  3     select '7.3%' from dual
  4    )

Query looks like this:
  5  select col
  6  from test
  7  where instr(col, '%') = 0;

COL
----
5.3

SQL>

Another option might be to use regular expressions:
where regexp_like(col, '%');


If I got it wrong (and you, actually, want those values), then use where instr(col, '%') > 0.
